# Error Copy android SDK folder from windows to mac?

Tags: macos, android-studio, gradle, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

What steps i followed:

- Deleted `SDK` folder placed on MAC after installing Android Studio
- Copy SDK folder from windows and pasted it on same location as previous SDK folder was placed .
- Now Following Errors Keeps occurring:

  - When Rebuilding Project `Gradle Build Error`
  - When Clicking on StandAlone SDK manager `Not found "my path" error=2 something something`
  - When clicking on `Run` button exception `adb not found` occur
  - And many other issues

**My Attempts in resolving issues:**

1 - Installed All Gradle build latest and previous and tried to change my `buildToolsVersion` and `support appcompat v7` on all of them finally one worked, build version `23.0.0` which is installed. (Hope Fully Resolved Gradle Build Error)

2 - Manually installed `Tools` folder for mac and replaced it with `Tools` folder in `SDK` folder

3 - Tried to Bribe my laptop and Android Studio , didn't work out though

Now why i did something like this? `To save my bandwidth` i have 78GB of `SDK` folder in windows and didn't want to waste my bandwidth installing all `SDK's` again , so Kindly suggest a workaround/solution

Comment: At the very least, anything in the Android SDK that is an executable will need to be re-downloaded since Windows .exe files will not run on OSX. This includes things in "build-tools" for each build tools version (e.g. aapt, aidl, zipalign etc.) and things in the "platform-tools" (e.g. adb, fastboot etc.)

Comment: Probably easiest way to accomplish this is to install the SDK on OSX using the standard installer, then copy over just the relevant platforms from the Windows version.